# How to create HTML element in Qt?

Tags: html, qt, webkit, qtwebkit

Qt has its own wrapper on WebKit (QWebNode, QWebElement, etc).

How can I create HTML element using that Qt wrapper (obtain QWebElement of new HTML element)?

If it can help, say we have `QWebFrame frame`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only method I found is to call `appendInside`, `appendOutside`, etc methods of existing `QWebElement` elements with `QString` html markup as an argument.

```
QWebElement existingElement;
existingElement.appendInside( '<div/>' );
QWebElement newElement = existingElement.lastChild();
```